# How do I 'git push' from a local machine to a Google Cloud Platform instance?

Tags: git, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files) for Google Cloud Platform describes a number of ways of transferring files to Google Compute Engine instances. But it does not mention how to use Git to do this. Also, while I have Google Cloud code repositories available under "Development" in the Web console, it's not clear to he how to associate these with Compute instances.

How do I associate a Git repository with a Google Compute Engine instance and `git push` from my local machine to that the instance repo?

Comment: That's an interesting idea but I have never seen it done in practice. People typically use CM tools such as Ansible, Chef, and Puppet. For simple cases I like Fabric, which is easy to learn, allows you to program your code pushes and host management tasks in Python, and works over SSH.

Answer (score 16):

Since an SSH service is running on GCE Linux VMs by default, simply follow these steps:

1. On your local computer run `gcloud auth login` to authorize gcloud to access Google Cloud Platform.
2. Run `gcloud compute config-ssh` to populate SSH config files with Host entries from each instance.
3. Test SSHing to your VM instance by running `ssh NAME.ZONE.PROJECT`
   Example: `ssh example-instance.us-central1-a.MY-PROJECT`
4. Set up an empty repository on your VM:

   `$ mkdir project.git` 
   `$ cd project.git` 
   `$ git init --bare`
5. On your local computer add the remote repository:

`git remote add origin NAME.ZONE.PROJECT:/<PATH>/project.git`

Now you should be able to push your project to the Git repository on your VM.

Comment: Can't I just create a repo on the instance and push with SSH?

Comment: I updated my answer with steps required on GCE VM to create a Git repo server.

Comment: That looks right, but I don't see the relevance of the first part now. It's just a matter of pushing the the repo over SSH.

Comment: If you can elaborate further on your question and use case, I may be able to provide more information.

Comment: Just what you've described. It's just that the first part of the answer has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use gcloud to clone the repo

```
gcloud source repos clone <<repo>> --projec=<<project_id>>
```

after you can use git from command line, don't know how works integration with tools, but from command line works really good (at least on MacOs and Linux)

Edit:
Looking after you edit the question, I will use a cloud build job to do it, even if could be more complicate that it should. Just trigger the job that does the copy on push on a directory and after use one of the method for transfer the file.

Answer (score -2):

You have to define remote for this action. (using git remote add/set-url)

---

## ***remote add***

```
# Add new remote
git remote add godaddy1 $user1@foo.com:~/root.git
```

---

## ***remote set-url***

```
# replace the current remote if want to replace instead of adding a new one
git remote set-url godaddy $user1@foo.com:~/root.git
```

---

## ***List all remotes***

```
# List all remotes
git remote -v
```

Comment: But how do I specify my Google Compute Instance, or associate my repo with the instance?

Comment: You need to find out the url of your google git repo and set it up. it can be found under your google account

Comment: Here is a link : https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes

Comment: How do I associate the git Google git repo with a Google Compute Instance? Starting from "create instance", I don't see any repo associated.

Comment: yes you can. follow the instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I just see a way to specify a project with `<project-id>`. So I have repos on the Google cloud, but what's missing is: how do associate a repo with an instance?

Comment: My question must not be clear. I've got all that. I've got a Google cloud repo. I've got a local repo that uses the Google cloud repo as a remote. That's just basic git. The question has nothing to do with that. The question is how to I associate the repo with a VM instance? (E.g., how to a control what's on my instance by pushing with Git?)

Comment: So if you are just trying to put files on your instance, why do you need GIT ?
Surely, just copy them with scp??